# How do I overwrite rows of text going down in vi / vim?

Tags: vim, vi

In vi / vim I would like to overwrite rows of text going down the page. Similar to overwriting characters in a line - I press `R`, then paste and the charcters are overwritten, but instead I want to do the same going down the page.

**Example:**

I have a file with the following text in it:

```
 var1: 7FBzezsLKyzYmVeM
 var2: kL8RIBJVNrlEUyYV
 var3: 1FkmXFSXtH4msKnL
```

I would like to replace those lines with the following:

```
 var1: 7PmuHKKRx9OYt9mR
 var2: nuRAS5dAKfUrvECJ
 var3: km11I7HuXOWuu43X
```

What I would normally do is delete the existing lines and paste the new lines in their place, or the other way around.

The new text comes from the paste buffer whether yanked or copied from elsewhere.

I have searched extensively, but cannot find any reference to how to do this. Even with macros I cannot think of how I would go about doing this.

Has anyone managed to do this? If this is not possible then fine I know for sure.

Comment: What do you mean by "replace rows of text going down the page"? Do you want to replace columns of text? Where do you take the replacements from?

Comment: The text would originate from the paste buffer, whether yanked or copied from elsewhere.

Comment: `3S` and paste with the central bottom of th mouse?

Comment: Sorry I am not making myself clear, the only way I can explain it is to have the `R` functionality - i.e. you insert the text and all the text underneith is overwritten - you dont have to specify how many characters are to be overwritten or deleted them first. All this but down the page, not across the page

Comment: Thanks @JJoao - that is what I am after but not to have to specify the number of rows / lines first, just insert and however many lines are insterted are overwritten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this:

- copy / yank the lines you want to copy
- switch to the buffer you want to change
- <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>

Translation:

- <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> enters visual replace mode (cf. `:h gR`)
- <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> - pastes from register `0` (see `:h i_CTRL-R`, `:h quote0`)
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> - leaves replace mode.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with this!! gR is exactly what I am after!!

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean.

go to first matching line, then use

```
.,.+2d
r /tmp/var
```

- `.,.+2d` will delete the 3 line (adjust 2 to your need)
- `r /tmp/var` will read (insert) template file.

Comment: Yes as I say that is pretty much what i do at the moment, so I just wanted to know if there is a way to overwrite rather than delete then paste / insert.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `gR` (as suggested by @SatoKatsura) is great if the length of old and new is identical. For the general case, this doesn't work, though, and a different approach must be taken.
I need this so often, I wrote a plugin to simplify and allow maximum speed: [ReplaceWithRegister](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703).

This plugin offers a two-in-one `gr` command that replaces text covered by a {motion} / text object, entire line(s) or the current selection with the contents of a register; the old text is deleted into the black-hole register, i.e. it's gone. It transparently handles many corner cases and allows for a quick repeat via the standard `.` command. Should you not like it, its page has links to alternatives.